# How to split a data set one below the other?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

There is a google sheet coordinate set. It has a lot of coordinate values inside a single cell. As in the picture below. [image]
Here coordinate as N, E, Z. Here after the first coordinate 1 we have gone to the next line inside the same cell. I tried to separate the ones I wanted for one cell but it didn't work.

```
    function sepCoordi() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Coordi");

  //get data to array
  var coor = sheet.getRange("A2:B47").getValues();
  var one = coor[0][1];
  Logger.log(one);

  var onesplit = one.split(" ");
  Logger.log(onesplit);  
}
```

Result

[image]

This is how I want it `[[80.091821,6.842871,98.23][80.091861,6.842881,106.1][80.091905,6.842894,109.25][....][....]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script and your showing Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sepCoordi() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Coordi");
  var coor = sheet.getRange("A2:B47").getValues();
  
  // I modified below script.
  var values = coor.flatMap(([,b]) => b.split("\n").map(e => e.split(",").map(f => f.trim())));
  console.log(values)
}
```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you. With your help I used the for loop to get the first coordinate of each cell, but I also need to get the last coordinate of the same cell. How to take? first ```80.091821,6.842871,98.23``` done. i want last of every cells ```80.092848,6.842632,115.58```

Comment: @TipVisor Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `i want last of every cells 80.092848,6.842632,115.58`, in this case, how about `var values = coor.flatMap(([,b]) => [b.split("\n").pop()].map(e => e.split(",").map(f => f.trim())))`? By this, the last line of each cell value is retrieved. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Restructure Data

```
function restructure() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange("A1:B5").getValues().map(r => r[1].split('\n')).flat().map(e => e.split(','));
  console.log(vs);
  sh.getRange(1,3,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Sheet 0:

[image]

```
Execution log
4:24:45 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:24:45 PM  Info    [ [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  [ '4', '5', '6' ],
  [ '7', '8', '9' ],
  [ '10', '11', '12' ],
  [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  [ '4', '5', '6' ],
  [ '7', '8', '9' ],
  [ '10', '11', '12' ],
  [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  [ '4', '5', '6' ],
  [ '7', '8', '9' ],
  [ '10', '11', '12' ],
  [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  [ '4', '5', '6' ],
  [ '7', '8', '9' ],
  [ '10', '11', '12' ],
  [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  [ '4', '5', '6' ],
  [ '7', '8', '9' ],
  [ '10', '11', '12' ] ]
4:24:46 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Posted into Sheet0:

| C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |

[Array Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)